# Dynamic imports in one bundle?

Tags: rollupjs

I'm trying to bundle a ESM source file that includes dynamic imports like `e.push(import("./polyfills/dom.js"))`. Not my code, so I can't change it.

With `--experimentalCodeSplitting`, Rollup would try to *code split*, but I actually want a single all-in-one bundle.

Is it possible with Rollup to include all these imports in one file?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was using an older version of Rollup (0.58.2). It works fine with never versions (0.60.1).